# proof verification on $f_{n}$ uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I want to show that $f_{n}(x)=x^{2}+ (-1)^{n}\frac{cos(n\sqrt{n})}{n}\rightarrow x^{2}$

i just said $  \left | f_{n}(x) \right |\leq  x^{2} +\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow x^{2}$

is this correct? is there a better way to show this?

for uni

$\left \| f_{n}-f \right \|_{\infty }=\left \| (-1)^{n}\frac{cos(n\sqrt{n})}{n} \right \|\leq \frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: In my opinion, it is correct.